# Configurar minDate e maxDate no Datepicker do jQuery-UI

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

Queria saber como usar corretamente o `maxDate` e o `minDate`.

Ex.: meu calendario começar em 1970 e terminar em 2017:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                  $('.datepicker').datepicker({              
                    format:'yyyy-mm-dd',
                    i18n:{
                      months: ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
                      monthsShort: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'],
                      weekdays: ['Domingo', 'Segunda', 'Terça', 'Quarta', 'Quinta', 'Sexta', 'Sabádo'],
                      weekdaysAbbrev: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sab'],
                      weekdaysShort: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sab'],
                      today: 'Hoje',
                      clear: 'Limpar',
                      close: 'Pronto',
                      labelMonthNext: 'Próximo mês',
                      labelMonthPrev: 'Mês anterior',
                      labelMonthSelect: 'Selecione um mês',
                      labelYearSelect: 'Selecione um ano',
                      selectMonths: true,
                      selectYears: 4,
                      cancel: 'Cancelar',
                      clear: 'Limpar',  
                      },
                    });
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

No DatePicker, os atributos `maxDate` e `minDate` definem a data máxima e mínima consecutivamente que o usuário pode selecionar no calendário.

Existem 3 formas distintas para configurar esses delimitadores:

## String em forma de período:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({
  maxDate: "+2y +1m +1w +4d",
  minDate: "-1m -1w -2d"
});
```

Onde `+2y +1m +1w +4d` representa **2 anos, 1 mês, 1 semana e 4 dias** contados à partir de hoje (dia corrente).

Legenda:

- `y` para anos;
- `m` para meses;
- `w` para semanas;
- e `d` para dias.

---

## Objeto da classe `Date`:

Você também pode passar um objeto da classe `Date`:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({
  maxDate: new Date(2019, 12, 31),
  minDate: new Date(2005, 1, 10)
});
```

Onde `Date(2019, 12, 31)` é equivalente ao dia 31 de Dezembro de 2019.

> Leitura recomendada: [JavaScript - Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

---

## Número de dias:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({
  maxDate: 15,
  minDate: -20
});
```

Onde `15` representa 15 dias a partir de hoje (dia corrente) e `-20` representa 20 dias antes de hoje (dia corrente) (`-1` é ontem e `1` é amanhã).

---

Todas os 3 métodos estão descritos na documentação (link a seguir). Agora é só aplicar no seu próprio DatePicker!

> Leitura recomendada: [jQuery-UI DatePicker - maxDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate)
>
> Leitura recomendada: [jQuery-UI DatePicker - minDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate)

Comment: com o ".selector" não funciona, ainda continua aparecendo anos infinitamente :(

Comment: Uai, isso aí foi um exemplo. Você vai aplicar isso no seu próprio datepicker conforme sua necessidade. No seu caso, o `.seletor` é o seu `.datepicker`.

Answer (score -2):

Só uma observação, 
new Date(2019, 12, 31) é equivalente a 31 de Janeiro de 2020, pois o mês começa em 0 (zero). 
Date(2019, 11, 31), assim é equivalente a 31 de Dezembro de 2019.
Date(2019, 00, 31), assim é equivalente a 31 de Janeiro de 2019.